# Volleyball Player Combination

Tags: algorithm, combinations

Some Background:
In volleyball, players play in pools to determine rankings. Teams are pairs of players. Matches are a pair of players vs another pair of players. For this example, lets assume there is only one court the match can be played on and when a player isn't playing, they are sitting/waiting. The number of players in a pool will be between 4 and 7. If there are 8 players in a pool, they would just break it into 2 pools of 4 instead.

**I want to calculate the least number of matches in order for each player to play with every other player.**

For instance, a 4 player pool will have the following teams:

```
import itertools
players = [1,2,3,4]
teams = [t for t in itertools.combinations(players,2)]
print 'teams:'
for t in teams:
    print t
```

Outputs:

```
teams:
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
```

and the number of matches:

```
matches = []
for match in itertools.combinations(teams,2):
    # A player cannot be on both teams at the same time
    if set(match[0]) & set(match[1]) == set():
        matches.append(match)

for match in matches:
    print match
```

Outputs:

```
((1, 2), (3, 4))
((1, 3), (2, 4))
((1, 4), (2, 3))
```

Which is correct but this algorithm breaks when I add a 5th player to the pool:

```
((1, 2), (3, 4))
((1, 2), (3, 5))
((1, 2), (4, 5))
((1, 3), (2, 4))
((1, 3), (2, 5))
((1, 3), (4, 5))
((1, 4), (2, 3))
((1, 4), (2, 5))
((1, 4), (3, 5))
((1, 5), (2, 3))
((1, 5), (2, 4))
((1, 5), (3, 4))
((2, 3), (4, 5))
((2, 4), (3, 5))
((2, 5), (3, 4))
```

The teams are duplicated a number of times.

I tried to keep a list of teams that play but that algorithm turns out to be greedy. By this I mean when it gets to the (1,5) team, all the other teams [(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)] have already played and (1,5) never gets to play.

What I'm looking for:

```
((1,2), (3,4)) (player 5 waits)
((1,3), (2,5)) (player 4 waits)
((1,4), (3,5)) (player 2 waits)
((1,5), (4,2)) (player 3 waits)
((2,3), (4,5)) (player 1 waits)
```

Would it be easier to just calculate this by hand for each pool size or can this be done easily in python?

Thanks for the help!

---

Edit:
Removed Python tag. Any language will suffice and I can convert it to Python.

Comment: By "play with", do you mean "play in the same game as", "play on the same side as", or "play against"?

Comment: @user2357112 - "play with" I mean play on the same side. For example team (1,2) will only play against one other team in the 5 player pool. They aren't expected to play every other team.

Comment: Also - it's starting to look like in a 6 player pool, at least one team will play together twice.

Comment: Can someone explain why this gets many upvotes? I find it an uninformative title, and the question in bold isn't even related to Python at all. It's an interesting question, but does not belong in this category unless differently phrased.

Comment: @Dualinity: There's sample code in Python, and the OP is looking for solutions in Python. The tag is correct. As for the upvotes, they're probably there because this is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Executive summary:**

- In spite of its similarity to the NP-complete minimum set cover problem, this question is far from intractable. In particular -- and quite unlike minimum set cover -- we know a non-trivial best possible answer in advance.
- That answer is the number of teams divided by 2 (plus 1 when the N of teams is odd). We can never do better than that.
- Because of the structure of the problem, there are **many** acceptable solutions that achieve the best possible answer. You can stumble across them using a basic randomized greedy algorithm. As the N of teams grows large, your first random attempt is almost always successful.
- This approach is fast even for large numbers of teams (for example, just a couple of seconds for 1000 teams).

**Details:**

You can use the formula for k-combinations to determine the number of teams required so that every player is paired with every other player (with k = 2).

```
n_teams = n! / ( (n - k)! k! )

n     n_teams
--    --------
4     6
5     10
6     15
7     21
8     28
9     36
10    45
11    55      # n_teams always equals the sum of values in previous row
```

What about the minimum number of matches? I think it's simply n_teams divided by 2 (with some padding to handle an odd number of teams).

```
min_n_matches = (n_teams + (n_teams % 2)) / 2
```

I don't have a rigorous proof for this, but the intuition seems sound. Each time you add a new player, you can think of that as an additional **constraint**: you've just added one more player who cannot appear on both sides of a given match. At the same time, that new player generates a bunch of new team combinations. Those new teams are like **anti-constraints**: their presence makes it easier to form valid matches.

As you can see from the formula and data table above, the constraints (`n`) grow in linear fashion, but the anti-constraints (`n_teams`) grow much faster.

If that's true, you don't need a smart algorithm to solve the problem: **the greediest, most brain-dead algorithm will work fine**. Match the teams randomly (but validly), and if your first attempt fails, just try again. As the number of teams grows larger, you'll rarely fail on the first attempt.

There might be a better way to implement that idea, but here's an illustration that generates the teams and matches and confirms the assertions implied above.

```
import sys
import itertools
import random

def main():
    maxN = int(sys.argv[1])
    for n in range(4, maxN + 1):
        run_scenario(n)

def run_scenario(n):
    # Takes n of players.
    # Generates matches and confirms our expectations.
    k = 2
    players = list(range(1, n + 1))
    teams   = list(set(t) for t in itertools.combinations(players, k))

    # Create the matches, and count how many attempts are needed.
    n_calls = 0
    matches = None
    while matches is None:
        matches = create_matches(teams)
        n_calls += 1

    # Print some info.
    print dict(
        n       = n,
        teams   = len(teams),
        matches = len(matches),
        n_calls = n_calls,
    )

    # Confirm expected N of matches and that all matches are valid.
    T = len(teams)
    assert len(matches) == (T + (T % 2)) / 2
    for t1, t2 in matches:
        assert t1 & t2 == set()

def create_matches(teams):
    # Get a shuffled copy of the list of teams.
    ts = list(teams)
    random.shuffle(ts)

    # Create the matches, greedily.
    matches = []
    while ts:
        # Grab the last team and the first valid opponent.
        t1 = ts.pop()
        t2 = get_opponent(t1, ts)
        # If we did not get a valid opponent and if there are still
        # teams remaining, the greedy matching failed.
        # Otherwise, we must be dealing with an odd N of teams.
        # In that case, pair up the last team with any valid opponent.
        if t2 is None:
            if ts: return None
            else:  t2 = get_opponent(t1, list(teams))
        matches.append((t1, t2))

    return matches

def get_opponent(t1, ts):
    # Takes a team and a list of teams.
    # Search list (from the end) until it finds a valid opponent.
    # Removes opponent from list and returns it.
    for i in xrange(len(ts) - 1, -1, -1):
        if not t1 & ts[i]:
            return ts.pop(i)
    return None

main()
```

A sample of output. Notice how the number of calls very quickly tends toward 1.

```
> python volleyball_matches.py 100
{'matches': 3, 'n_calls': 1, 'teams': 6, 'n': 4}
{'matches': 5, 'n_calls': 7, 'teams': 10, 'n': 5}
{'matches': 8, 'n_calls': 1, 'teams': 15, 'n': 6}
{'matches': 11, 'n_calls': 1, 'teams': 21, 'n': 7}
{'matches': 14, 'n_calls': 4, 'teams': 28, 'n': 8}
{'matches': 18, 'n_calls': 1, 'teams': 36, 'n': 9}
{'matches': 23, 'n_calls': 1, 'teams': 45, 'n': 10}
{'matches': 28, 'n_calls': 1, 'teams': 55, 'n': 11}
{'matches': 33, 'n_calls': 1, 'teams': 66, 'n': 12}
...
{'matches': 2186, 'n_calls': 1, 'teams': 4371, 'n': 94}
{'matches': 2233, 'n_calls': 1, 'teams': 4465, 'n': 95}
{'matches': 2280, 'n_calls': 1, 'teams': 4560, 'n': 96}
{'matches': 2328, 'n_calls': 1, 'teams': 4656, 'n': 97}
{'matches': 2377, 'n_calls': 1, 'teams': 4753, 'n': 98}
{'matches': 2426, 'n_calls': 1, 'teams': 4851, 'n': 99}
{'matches': 2475, 'n_calls': 1, 'teams': 4950, 'n': 100}
```

Comment: Not a proof, but very nice.

Comment: Excellent response to the question at hand!

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but when I tried a random shuffling (see below), the number of calls definitely did not decrease as the pool size increased.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Python, but I couldn't resist trying it in Ruby.  Hopefully this will translate readily to Python.  If you don't know Ruby, I'll be happy to explain what's going on here:

```
num_players = gets.to_i
players = (1..num_players).to_a
teams = players.combination(2).to_a

def shuffle_teams( teams, players )
  shuffled_teams = teams.shuffle
  x = 0
  while x < shuffled_teams.length
    if shuffled_teams[x] - shuffled_teams[x + 1] == shuffled_teams[x]
      x += 2
    else
      return shuffle_teams( teams, players )
    end
  end
  x = 0
  while x < shuffled_teams.length
    team_1 = shuffled_teams[x]
    team_2 = shuffled_teams[x + 1]
    waiting = players.select do |player|
      ![team_1, team_2].flatten.include?(player)
    end
    print "(#{team_1}, #{team_2}), waiting: #{waiting}\n"
    x += 2
  end
end

shuffle_teams( teams, players )
```

This produces the correct output for 4 players:

```
([3, 4], [1, 2]), waiting: []
([1, 3], [2, 4]), waiting: []
([2, 3], [1, 4]), waiting: []
```

and for 5 players:

```
([2, 4], [1, 3]), waiting: [5]
([1, 5], [3, 4]), waiting: [2]
([1, 4], [2, 5]), waiting: [3]
([3, 5], [1, 2]), waiting: [4]
([2, 3], [4, 5]), waiting: [1]
```

However, it does not work for 6 or 7 players because each of those results in an odd number of combinations.  How is this problem dealt with in real life?  Somehow, one team will have to play twice.

**Edit:** This script will now handle 6 or 7 player pools by duplicating one of the teams.  It should be easy to replicate in Python, as it simply relies on shuffling the array of teams until they settle into the appropriate order.  At first, I felt like I was cheating a bit with that approach, but given Anonymous's explanation that this is an NP-complete problem (assuming I understand correctly what that means :-), this may be the best way to solve the problem for small pools (it blows up with pools larger than 9 or so, depending on your system, but fortunately that's beyond the scope of our scenario).  Plus the random ordering has the advantage of being impersonal, which could come in handy if players get upset about having to play twice without being scored the second time!  Here's the script:

```
num_players = gets.to_i
players = (1..num_players).to_a
teams = players.combination(2).to_a

def shuffle_teams( teams, players )
  shuffled_teams = teams.shuffle
  x = 0
  while x < shuffled_teams.length
    if !shuffled_teams[x + 1]
      shuffled_teams[x + 1] = shuffled_teams.find do |team|
        shuffled_teams[x] - team == shuffled_teams[x]
      end
    end
    if shuffled_teams[x] - shuffled_teams[x + 1] == shuffled_teams[x]
      x += 2
    else
      return shuffle_teams( teams, players )
    end   
  end
  x = 0
  while x < shuffled_teams.length
    team_1 = shuffled_teams[x]
    team_2 = shuffled_teams[x + 1]
    waiting = players.select do |player|
      ![team_1, team_2].flatten.include?(player)
    end
    print "(#{team_1}, #{team_2}), waiting: #{waiting}\n"
    x += 2
  end
end

shuffle_teams( teams, players )
```

And here's the output, with times:

```
4
([1, 4], [2, 3]), waiting: []
([1, 2], [3, 4]), waiting: []
([2, 4], [1, 3]), waiting: []

real    0m0.293s
user    0m0.035s
sys 0m0.015s

5
([4, 5], [1, 2]), waiting: [3]
([1, 4], [2, 3]), waiting: [5]
([2, 5], [1, 3]), waiting: [4]
([2, 4], [3, 5]), waiting: [1]
([3, 4], [1, 5]), waiting: [2]

real    0m0.346s
user    0m0.040s
sys 0m0.010s

6
([3, 4], [1, 2]), waiting: [5, 6]
([3, 5], [2, 4]), waiting: [1, 6]
([3, 6], [1, 5]), waiting: [2, 4]
([1, 6], [2, 5]), waiting: [3, 4]
([2, 3], [4, 6]), waiting: [1, 5]
([2, 6], [4, 5]), waiting: [1, 3]
([5, 6], [1, 4]), waiting: [2, 3]
([1, 3], [2, 4]), waiting: [5, 6]

real    0m0.348s
user    0m0.035s
sys 0m0.020s

7
([1, 6], [4, 5]), waiting: [2, 3, 7]
([2, 6], [1, 4]), waiting: [3, 5, 7]
([2, 7], [1, 3]), waiting: [4, 5, 6]
([3, 4], [2, 5]), waiting: [1, 6, 7]
([3, 5], [2, 4]), waiting: [1, 6, 7]
([1, 7], [5, 6]), waiting: [2, 3, 4]
([6, 7], [1, 5]), waiting: [2, 3, 4]
([3, 6], [4, 7]), waiting: [1, 2, 5]
([1, 2], [5, 7]), waiting: [3, 4, 6]
([3, 7], [4, 6]), waiting: [1, 2, 5]
([2, 3], [1, 6]), waiting: [4, 5, 7]

real    0m0.332s
user    0m0.050s
sys 0m0.010s
```

Comment: I'll have to grab the volleyball sheet the next time I play and see how they did it. I'm pretty sure they just calculated it out by hand like I did for the 5 player pool.  I thought it would be interesting to have an algorithm to automate it.

Comment: I'd be interested to know. If they solve the problem by having a team play twice, this could be done in my script by arbitrarily duplicating one of the combinations and pushing it to the end of the teams array. If they do it by having one team sit out, this could be done by popping the last combination in the teams array.

Comment: The answer from Anonymous with the NP complete algorithm also has duplicates for the 6 player pool. I'm starting to think that at least one team will have to play together twice so all teams can play together at least once. If this is the case in real life, the team that plays together twice just wouldn't get any points for their second match.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that 4 and 5 player pools result in 6 and 10 team combinations respectively, so you can divide them evenly into two-team matches. But 6 and 7 player pools result in 15 and 21 combinations, so you either have to repeat a team or leave a team out to make the number even.

Answer (score 1):

You can express this as a set-covering problem. With 4 players, take the set of all (unordered) pairs of players:

```
PP := {{0,1}, {0,2}, {0,3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}}
```

A possible match is an unordered pair of these pairs such that you don't have the same player on both sides. Here, the possible matches are:

```
M := {{{0,1},{2,3}}, {{0,2},{1,3}}, {{0,3},{1,2}}}
```

Your problem is now that you want to find the smallest subset of this set such that its union is the set of all player-pairs, PP.

This is an instance of [the minimum set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) which is NP complete. Perhaps restricting the sets to pairs gives an easier solution, but it won't be surprising if not.

Since you're limiting to smallish sets, it's quite viable to just to solve it by brute-force.

We know that it'll take at least `ceil(N * (N-1) / 4)` matches (since there's `N * (N-1) / 2` different pairs, and each match can cover at most 2 new pairs). That gives us an algorithm.

```
import itertools

def mincover(n):
    pairs = set(map(tuple, itertools.combinations(range(n), 2)))
    matches = itertools.combinations(pairs, 2)
    matches = [m for m in matches if not(set(m[0]) & set(m[1]))]
    for subset_size in xrange((len(pairs) + 1) // 2, len(pairs) + 1):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(matches, subset_size):
            cover = set()
            for s in subset: cover |= set(s)
            if cover == pairs:
                return subset

for i in xrange(4, 8):
    print i, mincover(i)
```

It's quite slow, especially for 6 and 7 players. This could be improved a bit by a hand-coded search that doesn't consider matches that don't add new player-pairs, and by using symmetry and always including `{{0,1}, {2,3}}`.

Comment: This calculates pretty quick up to the 6 player pool but it's been churning on the 7 player pool for almost an hour now.  The results for the 5th player pool are different than mine but it is still correct. The 6 player pool outputs 8 matches but one team plays together twice.  I'm not sure if there is anyway around this.

Comment: With 6 players there's 15 pairs and each match consists of two pairs. So there'll always be a pair that plays together twice.

Comment: Perhaps the analogy to the minimum set cover problem takes us down an overly difficult path. In this questsion we already know the best-case outcome. If we have N teams (assume N is even for simplicity), the hard-limit minimum number of matches is N/2 (that's the best we could ever do). All we have to do is pair up the N teams in N/2 legal matches and we're done. I think such pairings are easy to find greedily.

Answer (score 0):

There's got to be a better way to do this, but here's a start:

```
import itertools
import operator
from copy import deepcopy as clone

def getPossibleOpponents(numPlayers):
    matches = list(itertools.combinations(itertools.combinations(range(1,numPlayers+1), 2), 2))
    possibleMatches = [match for match in matches if len(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(match)))==4]
    answer, playedTeams = {}, set()
    opponents = {}
    for team, teams in itertools.groupby(possibleMatches, key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
        playedTeams.add(team)
        opponents[team] = [t for t in next(teams) if t!=team]

    return opponents

def updateOpponents(opponents, playedTeams):
    for team in playedTeams:
        if team in opponents:
            opponents.pop(team)
    for k,v in opponents.items():
        opponents[k] = [team for team in v if team not in playedTeams]

def teamSeatings(opponents, answer=None):
    if answer is None:
        answer = {}
    if not len(opponents):
        if not(len(answer)):
            return None
        print(answer)
            sys.exit(0)

    for k,v in opponents.items():
        if not v:
            return None

        newOpponents = clone(opponents)
        for away in opponents[k]:
            if k in newOpponents:
                newOpponents.pop(k)
            answer[k] = away
            updateOpponents(newOpponents, {itertools.chain.from_iterable(i[0] for i in answer.items())})
            teamSeatings(newOpponents, answer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    opps = getPossibleOpponents(5)
    teamSeatings(opps)
```

Comment: That answer doesn't look like a list of which sides play in which games. Are you sure this works?

Comment: @user2357112: I realized soon after I posted that there's one more step between my post and the answer. I'm working on that step now. So my post is not a working answer… yet

Answer (score 0):

In combinatorics this is called *Whist Round Robin*. Perhaps math experts interested in cominatorics are more inclined to play whist than beach volley ball? But that's another story.

### Whist Round Robin

The problem of scheduling a tournament with pairs consisting of two persons facing another two-person-team is called Whist Round Robin - Read more and find algorithms [here](http://www.devenezia.com/downloads/round-robin/).

It is easiest to implement in the case with *4n* number of players. The other three cases are constructed using ghost players and a ghost team. Players supposed to face the ghost team just sits out that round.

The basic idea is that one player is locked, lets say player one. The other players then "rotate" so that player 2 teams up with player 1 the first round and meets players 2 & 3. The next round player 1 stays and teams up with player 3 and they face players 2 & 4. See this visualization that I borrowed from the link above.

[image]

I've implemented the algorithms described there to schedule a [foosball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_football) torunament with similar characteristics as beach volley ball and it worked like a charm.

You should have no problem imlementing this in python. If you do - Please come back with some specific question. Good luck! :)

Comment: I don't think this is quite the same problem. The question is about minimizing the number of matches assuming a single match at a time, and a whist round robin has a series of rounds where multiple matches are played simultaneously. I don't see how to use a solution to WRR to minimize the number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

A good model for your problem is that of a **complete undirected graph**:

- Vertices represent the players.
- Edges represent a team of two players.

For each match setup, you want to draw **two edges** from the set of edges that **do not share a vertex**.
You keep drawing edge pairs until each edge has been drawn at least once.

[image: sample match schedule for the case n=5]

Since the number of edges in a complete graph of n vertices is `(n * (n - 1)) / 2` it is obvious that in the case of this number being odd, one edge has to be used twice.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to keep posting in Ruby, but I think I just cracked it, and I have to share.  Hopefully all my hard work helps you implement it in Python :).

This algorithm works without the random shuffling and recursive function I relied on before.  Thus it will work for much larger pools, not that we need to worry about them in this situation.

```
num_players = gets.to_i
players = (1..num_players).to_a
teams = players.combination(2).to_a
first_half = Float(teams.length / 2.0).ceil
first_half_teams = teams[0..(first_half - 1)]
second_half_teams = teams[first_half..-1]
possible_lineups = []
matches = []
matched = []

first_half_teams.each do |team|
  opponents = second_half_teams.select do |team_2|
    team - team_2 == team
  end
  possible_lineups << [team, opponents]
end

possible_lineups.each do |lineup|
  team_1 = lineup[0]
  team_2 = lineup[1].find do |team|
    !matched.include?(team)
  end
  if !team_2
    thief_team = possible_lineups.find do |test_team|
      test_team[1] - lineup[1] != test_team[1] &&
      test_team[1].find{ |opponent| !matched.include?(opponent) }
    end
    if thief_team
      new_opponent = thief_team[1].find{ |opponent| !matched.include?(opponent) }
      matched << new_opponent
      old_lineup = matches.find do |match|
        match[0] == thief_team[0]
      end
      team_2 = old_lineup[1]
      matches.find{ |match| match[0] == thief_team[0]}[1] = new_opponent
    else
      team_2 = second_half_teams.find do |team|
        lineup[0] - team == lineup[0]
      end
    end
  end
  matches << [team_1, team_2]
  matched << team_2
end

matches.each do |match|
  left_out = players.select{ |player| !match.flatten.include?(player) }
  print match, ", waiting: ", left_out, "\n"
end

print "greater: ", matches.flatten(1).find{ |team| matches.flatten(1).count(team) > teams.count(team) }, "\n"
print "less: ", matches.flatten(1).find{ |team| matches.flatten(1).count(team) < teams.count(team) }, "\n"
```

As a reality check, I'm having the script compare the final array of matches to the original array of unique player-pair combinations.  In cases where the number of player-pair combinations is even (eg pool size = 4 or 5), there should be no pairs that appear in the final matches array a greater or lesser number of times than they appear in the original combinations array (ie each pair should appear exactly once in each array).  In cases where the number of combinations is odd (n = 6 or 7), there should be exactly one pair that appears one more time in the matches array than it appears in the combinations array.  There should never be a pair that appears fewer times in the matches array than in the combinations array.  Here's the output:

```
4
[[1, 2], [3, 4]], waiting: []
[[1, 3], [2, 4]], waiting: []
[[1, 4], [2, 3]], waiting: []
greater: 
less: 

5
[[1, 2], [3, 5]], waiting: [4]
[[1, 3], [2, 4]], waiting: [5]
[[1, 4], [2, 5]], waiting: [3]
[[1, 5], [3, 4]], waiting: [2]
[[2, 3], [4, 5]], waiting: [1]
greater: 
less: 

6
[[1, 2], [3, 4]], waiting: [5, 6]
[[1, 3], [2, 6]], waiting: [4, 5]
[[1, 4], [3, 5]], waiting: [2, 6]
[[1, 5], [3, 6]], waiting: [2, 4]
[[1, 6], [4, 5]], waiting: [2, 3]
[[2, 3], [4, 6]], waiting: [1, 5]
[[2, 4], [5, 6]], waiting: [1, 3]
[[2, 5], [3, 4]], waiting: [1, 6]
greater: [3, 4]
less: 

7
[[1, 2], [3, 4]], waiting: [5, 6, 7]
[[1, 3], [4, 5]], waiting: [2, 6, 7]
[[1, 4], [3, 5]], waiting: [2, 6, 7]
[[1, 5], [3, 6]], waiting: [2, 4, 7]
[[1, 6], [3, 7]], waiting: [2, 4, 5]
[[1, 7], [4, 6]], waiting: [2, 3, 5]
[[2, 3], [4, 7]], waiting: [1, 5, 6]
[[2, 4], [5, 6]], waiting: [1, 3, 7]
[[2, 5], [6, 7]], waiting: [1, 3, 4]
[[2, 6], [5, 7]], waiting: [1, 3, 4]
[[2, 7], [3, 4]], waiting: [1, 5, 6]
greater: [3, 4]
less:
```

Note to FMc: Your comments helped me refine my thinking on this problem.  The "brain-dead" algorithm gets you close, but not quite to a solution.  When n > 4, there always seems to be one pair of players left without an opposing pair when you use a purely greedy algorithm.  My algorithm deals with this by going back and taking an eligible opposing pair from an already matched team, if and only if the latter team can use another opposing pair that has not already been used.  This seems to be the only fix required (besides adjusting for odd numbers of combinations), and as far as I can tell it only needs to be done once.